# awk on a field captured by awk

Tags: awk

I can't find a proper way to parse a field that was already retrieved by awk.

Using awk I collect the nth element that looks like that:

```
bbr:(bw:492.2Mbps,mrtt:0.412,pacing_gain:1.25,cwnd_gain:2)
```

I would like to parse once again this nth field in order to collect the data:

```
$1 = 492.2; 
$2 = 0.41;
$3 = 1.25; 
$4 = 2;
```

If you have any suggestion, you would be pleased to hear it

G.

Comment: awk has `split()` function. check the man page to know how it works.

Comment: Please post the `awk` command which produces that output

Comment: Thank you Kent, that was the function I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the string is stored to a `file`, read to `$0`, cleaned, `split`ed to hash `a` and outputed in a `for` loop:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/^.*\(|\)$/,"");n=split($0,a,/[:,]/);for(i=2;i<=n;i+=2)print a[i]}' file
492.2Mbps
0.412
1.25
2
```

Explained:

```
gsub(/^.*\(|\)$/,"")     # clean outside of parentheses, including them
n=split($0,a,/[:,]/)     # split to a 
for(i=2;i<=n;i+=2)       # further process every other element in a
    print a[i]           # you could remove the Mbps and what not here
```

Comment: Thank you James, that's what I needed.

Comment: There's nothing GNU awk specific about that script. Also, you don't need the `,$0` arg for gsub() as that's the default.